# How to figure out which audio file has more volume level using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, volume

I am facing an issue and I don't even know how to describe it technically so I am explaining my issue in plain English (Sorry if someone gets offended)

I have many audio files which I play them in the background in a video. But unfortunately the audio files have different level of volume level:- some audio files have low volume level whereas some audio files have very high level of volume.

Is there any way to reduce the volume level in those audio files where volume level is high (leaving low volume audio files as it is) using ffmpeg. Or something like this

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could use `loudnorm` from `ffmpeg` http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm. I recommend organizing all the audio files in a folder and apply `loudnorm` to each audio file.